# Добавить сетевой файловый ресурс в "другие места" в Gnome3

Tags: linux, samba, gnome

Наутилус, файловый менеджер Гнома, показывает на закладке «Другие места» ресурсы выданные Avahi, Samba, Google Drive. Самбу и Авахи показывает только в локальной сети.

Как сделать чтоб там отображался ресурс самбы из другой сети?

Протокол любой который поддерживает блокировки на уровне файлов подойдет (samba, nfs)

Подойдет любой способ, который можно заскриптовать. Ярлыки и закладки не интересно - сейчас сделано так.

Домена на виндовс нет т.к. нет виндовс в сети. Есть wins на самбе.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что в данном случае гномом используется не собственный велосипед, а либо программа smbclient, либо какой-нибудь библиотечный вызов из каких-нибудь samba-вских библиотек.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, определённо. И вероятно надо донастроить самбу, чтоб она смотрела хосты в других сетях. По умолчанию самба клиент ищет в нетбиос - в локальной сети только